# Boto + Python + AWS S3: How to get last_modified attribute of specific file?

Tags: python, python-2.7, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

It’s possible to get last_modified attribute:

```
import boto3

s3 = boto3.resource('s3')

bucket_name = 'bucket-one'
bucket = s3.Bucket(bucket_name)

for obj in bucket.objects.all():
    print obj.last_modified
```

But it does so for all the objects in a bucket. How can I get the `last_modified` attribute for one specific object/file under a bucket?

Answer (score 3):

Hope this helps you....

This will get the last modified time of a particular object in an S3 bucket

```
import boto3
import time
from pprint import pprint

s3 = boto3.resource('s3',region_name='S3_BUCKET_REGION_NAME')
bucket='BUCKET_NAME'
key='OBJECT_NAME'
summaryDetails=s3.ObjectSummary(bucket,key)
timeFormat=summaryDetails.last_modified
formatedTime=timeFormat.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
pprint( 'Bucket name is '+ bucket + ' and key name is ' + key + ' and last modified at time '+ formatedTime)
```

Thanks....

Answer (score 2):

```
bucket_name = 'bucket-one'
file_name = 'my_file'

object = s3.Object(bucket_name, file_name)
print object.last_modified
```

or simply:

```
print s3.Object(bucket_name, file_name).last_modified
```